# Timeout occur sometimes when executing a Store Procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure, which works if I execute manually. But sometimes I see timeout exception on running this Stored Procedure. Is this is due to MERGE, http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrUpdateMobileUser]
(
    @ID BIGINT
    ,@Name NVARCHAR(255)
)
AS
BEGIN



    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TranCount INT;
    SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF @TranCount = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ELSE
            SAVE TRANSACTION InsertOrUpdateMobileUser;

        MERGE INTO MobileUsers MU
        USING (SELECT @ID AS ID) T ON (MU.ID = T.ID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET [Name] = CASE WHEN @Name IS NULL OR @Name = '' THEN [Name] ELSE @Name END                                    
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT ([Name])
            VALUES (@Name)

            SELECT   *                                  
            FROM     MobileUsers
            WHERE    ID = @ID;

LBEXIT:
        IF @TranCount = 0
            COMMIT;
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
        SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();

        IF @XState = -1
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
            rollback
        IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION InsertOrUpdateMobileUser;

        RAISERROR ('InsertOrUpdateMobileUser: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Please post the execution plan.

Comment: @usr, http://www.speedyshare.com/6YZ3n/download/Plan.sqlplan

Comment: @usr, the above sql is updated a little to make it more readable

Comment: This query is so low-cost that I cannot imagine it being the cause for the timeout. Maybe the server is completely overloaded sometimes. This can happen due to backups or index operations. I have also seen this with synchronous mirroring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You differentiate between two execution methods. What are they, exactly? You mean that it works if run only the code of the procedure, and doesn't work when you EXECUTE the proc? Of it works through EXECUTE, and fails in a job?

Timeouts only concern client applications. You have SqlCommand .CommandTimeout property in .NET, and in Management Studio there's Tools>Options>Query Execution>Command Timeout. If you have a job, then it should run infinitely, there's even no option to set the timeout in Sql Server Agent.

Comment: Timeout means it is taking more than 90 seconds. It works fine but sometimes it is time-outing.